# i deployed my web application .ear file in websphere and trying to access application api through web browser. getting this error

Tags: web-applications, websphere

=>com.tangosol.net.messaging.ConnectionException: could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses: [127.0.0.1:9099]; make sure the "remote-addresses" configuration element contains an address and port of a running TcpAcceptor

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don`t post just an error message. Explain what want to achive, and waht you tries so far.

Comment: i deployed my web application .ear file in websphere and trying to access application api through web browser.

Comment: `could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses: [127.0.0.1:9099` - Probably incorrect port. WebSphere by default is using 9080.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would like to see more details for error messages from the log, but based on this small snippet, my guess is that the application is trying to connect to a `com.tangosol.net.messaging` service at `127.0.0.1:9099`. A quick online search suggests that this package name is related to Oracle Coherence.

As far as `127.0.0.1:9099`, this means it's trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) which means the same machine where WebSphere is running, and on port `9099`.

If you are running Oracle Coherence on the same machine as WebSphere, then make sure that Coherence is started when starting WebSphere or find the port that it's running on and configure the application to use the proper port.

If you are not running Coherence on the same machine as WebSphere, then if this is a test environment, you'll need to install Coherence, or if this is not a test environment, then you should configure the application to replace `127.0.0.1` with the host name of the machine that's running Coherence (and ensure the port is correct and any firewalls between WebSphere and the target machine enable this access).